# Logic equivalent expression $(p\lor q)\iff \neg(\neg p\land\neg q)$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have a simple logic equivalence expression.  I'm thinking there must be a name for this principal of OR inversion.  Can anyone help put a name to this idea?  Link to expression calc below.
$$(p\lor q)\iff  \neg(\neg p\land\neg q)$$

https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/discrete-mathematics/truth-table-calculator/?f=%28p%E2%88%A8q%29%3D%7E%28%7Ep%E2%88%A7%7Eq%29&v=

My question was flagged as not meeting the standard for questions.  To explain my questions purpose it was to find a concise terminology to refer to this logic equivalence in the rare instances it comes up in computer code logic refactoring.  My use case was with a particular rdms system which inexplicably choked on OR operations, but refactoring to not use OR operations would sometimes drastically improve performance.

Comment: This is De Morgan's law mixed with double negation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De Morgan’s law for logic states that:
$$ \neg (p \lor q) \iff \neg p \land \neg q \\ \neg (p \land q) \iff \neg p \lor \neg q$$
Then if we start with $\neg p$ and $\neg q$ we obtain:
$$ \neg(\neg p \land \neg q) \iff p \lor q$$
I suppose you could call this the substitution of de morgan’s law, or more accurately de morgan’s law with double negation. This is not specifically named however.

Comment: De Morgan's Law**s**